# R plyr alply error "wrong dimension" on degenerate array

Tags: r, slice, plyr

I am using function alply from R-package plyr to apply a function to each array along the 3d dimension of a 3d-array. The function returns a matrix.

Sometimes, the first or second dimension of the array is only of size one, i.e. is degenerate.
In such cases, I get errors from alply.

Here is a minimal example:

```
require(abind)  # adrop
#x <- array(1:6, dim=c(2,3,2))  # this works fine
x <- array(1:6, dim=c(1,3,2))   # has only one row: degenerate dimension
subCols <- function(mat){ mat[,1:2, drop=FALSE]}
subCols( adrop(x[,,1 ,drop=FALSE],3) )
alply(x, 3, subCols )   # error on wrong dimensions when only one row
```

I expected that alply gives me a list with two entries, each a matrix with one row and two columns.
However, I get the error "wrong numbers of dimensions" (actually in german: "falsche Anzahl von Dimensionen").

What is the best way to go forward?
Knowing the right option to alply / Trying to handle the special cases with conditionals / Writing a specialized alply replacement / ...

Best regards
thomasw

edit: I am using R version 3.0.2 on Windows, plyr version 1.8.1

Comment: Handling the special case inside function subCols is difficult, as it cannot distinguish between getting a row and a column vector:
x <- array(1:6, dim=c(1,3,2))   # has only one row: degenerate dimension
x <- array(1:6, dim=c(3,1,2))   # has only one column

Comment: The specialized alply case: Found function twListArrDim: [link]https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/twMisc/R/arrayExtract.R?view=markup&revision=101&root=twsnowfall
 
lapply( twListArrDim(x,3), subCols)